# How can I drop multiple primary keys in phpmyadmin tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am working with phpmyadmin.I created a table with one primary key and 5 fields. But now all the integer fields have turned into a primary key. I tried using drop command but it doesn't help. How can I remove all primary keys from the table?

Comment: Please show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`.

Answer (score 37):

Just open up the `Structure` tab on your phpmyadmin table. After the structure description, there should be a `Indexes` section where you'll see all indexes, including your primary keys. There you'll be able to either modify or remove any primary key you may have defined.

**---- EDIT ----**

[image]

Comment: can u please specify it

Comment: I've added a snapshot, sorry as it is in spanish, but the structure has to bee the same. As you can see, you've an `Indexes` section, and there you can delete it (called 'Eliminar' in my snapshot) or edit it ('Editar').

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY fieldname INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, i will tell you the Steps to do:

Step 1: Go to the Relation View.

Step 2: Indexes.

Step 3: You will find Keyname as PRIMARY.

Step 4: Drop the PRIMARY

Step 5: Ok.

Thanks.

Here all the Steps images, you can follow it for your easy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may have indexed a column as a FOREIGN KEY, in this cas you should delete this index and then you will be able to modify or delete your PRIMARY KEY.